# The derivative of $ \tan x$ is $ \sec^2 x$. Why?

Tags: calculus

I understand why the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$, and why the derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$ in a geometric way.

But I can not understand why the derivative of $\tan x$ is $\sec^2 x$.

Can someone please explain this in a visual, geometric way using the unit circle?

Comment: Use the limit definition of derivative.

Comment: If you understand the derivatives of sin and cosine, and you understand the quotient rule for derivatives in general, then this falls out of that. As to whether there's a good geometric picture, I'm not sure, but as time goes on it will become increasingly important to not rely on geometry.

Comment: How have you understood the derivatives of $\sin,\cos$?

Comment: This might help you figure out why it is: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Circle-trig6.svg/1280px-Circle-trig6.svg.png

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076000/geometric-proof-that-fracdd-theta-tan-theta-1-tan2-theta

Comment: @HansLundmark that is pretty much the correct answer, it just needs to be written down a little bit more formally.

Comment: @user347489: I just added another answer, where you get $1/\cos^2 \theta$ more directly, rather than $1 + \tan^2 \theta$.

Comment: Here's another question which covers all the trig functions, not just the tangent: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299682/geometric-intuition-for-derivatives-of-basic-trig-functions

Answer (score 7):

The following is maybe a little bit hand-wavy, but the idea is hopefully clear.

If $\theta$ is the angle $EAH$ in the figure, then $\tan \theta$ is the lenght of the segment $BC$. If we increase that angle slightly (or “infinitesimally”), then the segment $EF$ is approximately $d\theta$, and we would like to know the length of $CD$, since that's the change in $\tan \theta$.

Since the triangle $AHE$ is $\cos \theta$ times smaller than the triangle $ABC$, the segment $EF$ is $\cos \theta$ times shorter than $CG$. And $CG$ is in turn $\cos \theta$ times shorter than $CD$ (similar triangles; the angle $GCD$ is $\theta$ and the angle $CGD$ is $\pi/2$ up to an infinitesimal correction). So $EF$ is $\cos^2 \theta$ times shorter than $CD$, and thus
$$
d( \tan\theta ) = CD = \frac{EF}{\cos^2\theta} = \frac{d\theta}{\cos^2 \theta}
.
$$

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 4):

First, look at the graph of $\tan(x)$.

[image]

It has vertical asymptotes at integer multiples of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and is undefined at $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Observe that from $-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, the slope of $\tan(x)$ is always increasing. Notice that it increases faster from $-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq -\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and from $\dfrac{\pi}{4} \leq x \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Then, let's take a look at the graph of $\sec^2(x)$.

[image]

Observe that $\sec^2(x)$ is always positive as the slope of $\tan(x)$ was always positive. Also observe that $\sec^2(x)$ has vertical asymptotes at integer multiples of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. If we zone in on $-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, then we see that the value of $\sec^2(x)$ is greater as we approach $x=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ or $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. This is because we can think of the derivative as slope and previously saw that the slope was greatest near the asymptotes.

Therefore, it is natural for $\sec^2(x)$ to be the derivative of $\tan(x)$. The same technique will work for $\sin(x), \cos(x)$, and many others. If you are uncomfortable with the algebra then it is best draw a function and its derivative on graph paper.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of derivative
and the rule
$\tan(a+b)
=\dfrac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\tan(x+h)-\tan(x)
&=\dfrac{\tan(x)+\tan(h)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(h)}-\tan(x)\\
&=\dfrac{\tan(x)+\tan(h)-\tan(x)(1-\tan(x)\tan(h))}{1-\tan(x)\tan(h)}\\
&=\dfrac{\tan(h)+\tan^2(x)\tan(h)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(h)}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{\tan(x+h)-\tan(x)}{h}
&=\dfrac{\tan(h)+\tan^2(x)\tan(h)}{h(1-\tan(x)\tan(h))}\\
&=\dfrac{\tan(h)}{h}\dfrac{1+\tan^2(x)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(h)}\\
&\to 1+\tan^2(x)\\
&= 1+\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\\
&= 1+\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{\cos^2(x)}\\
&=\sec^2(x)\\
\end{array}
$

since,
as $h \to 0$,
$\dfrac{\tan(h)}{h}
\to 1$
and
$\tan(h) \to 0$.

Comment: If the OP can find a geometric interpretation for the sum-of-angles formula then this answer is probably the most promising

Comment: My thought, too.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to derive this would be the quotient rule, the other way is looking at the graph just like what Axion posted. I dont know how to derive it with unit circle/geometry way, sorry :) . But, instead of quotient rule i will just use product rule which is a bit inefficient because $cos(x)$ is in denominator (and i have to use chain rule for that), and it will do the trick anyway. So as you can see below the derivative of $tan(x)$ is just itself squared and the added by one, which by identities become $sec^{2}(x)$.

Edit : i just found the geometric way, please take a look on this post : [Geometric Proof that $\frac{d}{d\theta}(\tan{\theta}) = 1 + \tan^{2}{\theta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076000/geometric-proof-that-fracdd-theta-tan-theta-1-tan2-theta?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[image: Derivative of tan(x)]

Answer (score -2):

I can't explain it geometrically, but I can prove it algebraically:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dx} [\tan x] &= \frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \right] &\quad \text{Definition of } \tan x\\ &= \frac{\frac{d}{dx}[\sin x]\cdot (\cos x) - (\sin x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \left[\cos x \right]}{\cos^2 x} &\quad \text{Quotient Rule}\\ &= \frac{\cos^2 x + \sin^2x }{\cos^2 x} &\quad \text{Derivatives of } \sin x \text{ and } \cos x \\ &= {\frac{1}{\cos^2x}} &\quad \text{Pythagorean Identity} \\ &= {\sec^2 x}  &
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Is there no geometric explanation exist?any way thank you guys.

Comment: @Kamal There might be one, but I don't know it

Comment: You meant to write Derivatives of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig thanks, fixed

Answer (score -2):

You need to apply the quotient rule to $$\tan x =\frac {\sin x }{\cos x }$$

$$ (\tan x )'= \frac {(\sin x )' (\cos x) -(\sin x)(\cos x )'}{(\cos x )^2}=$$

$$ \frac {(\cos x ) (\cos x) -(\sin x)(-\sin x )}{(\cos x )^2} =$$

$$\frac {1}{\cos ^2 x} = \sec ^2 x$$